# Minefield x64 and x86 parallel

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, firefox

Is it possible to install a 64bit and a 32bit version of [Minefield](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/minefield/) in parallel? I know that it probably doesn't work with both running at the same time (given that they would want to share the profile folder), but I just would like to keep the option to go 32bit (with more support for plugins) when I need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install them in separate folders, but as you said - they make use of the same profile.

Comment: though, you can make a separate profile; using `firefox -profilemanager`

Comment: @lie - true. Perhaps use Firefox sync to get all your bookmarks and other such.

Comment: Well, I'm totally fine with them sharing the same profiles, settings and such. I just want a backup 32bit browser :)